# kestrel web api causes its client app failure of An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, kestrel-http-server

Thanks everyone for your generosity to share your knowledge and expertise.

I have a .Net 5 Web API application for uploading large files (>6GB). If this App is running from Visual Studio 2022's debug mode, it can accept any size of files. The client App using HttpClient can upload large files.
But if I start the web App from a command line or start by "dotnet run" command, it can only accept small files (<6KB) and the Client App can upload small files. If the client App tries to upload a large file (>3GB), the client App will show the following error.

```
{"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.."}
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Error while copying content to a stream.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at UploadFile.Program.Main(String[] args) in H:\Dev\DevProj\UploadFile\Program.cs:line 26
Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Overriding address(es) 'https://localhost:8001, http://localhost:8000'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: When you use vs debug to run the project, It will also host in kestrel or in IIS?

Comment: VS debugger runs it as Kestrel web.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that Visual Studio 2022 may cause the problem. Since our Intranet environment is still using Visual Studio 2019, I have to stay with .Net 5 and VS 2019 currently. This VS 2022 is only installed on a test machine with Internet access.
After I build the web service code from VS 2019, it is working perfectly without using VS debugging.